# Can LED work as pull-down for BOOT0?

Tags: led, stm32, gpio

Apologies if this is a silly question. I must be really overworked to not see an answer myself.

In short, I want to free GPIO pin by moving [LED](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/everlight-electronics-co-ltd/19-117Z-T1D-CN1P2B3X-3T/8535268) to BOOT0 of [STM32L4Q5](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32l4p5-q5.html).

According to datasheet BOOT0 automatically switches to analog mode after reset and then it can be used as PH3 GPIO. The straightforward way to use it is to add 10k pull-down and a FET to drive the LED. But what if I connect the pin to GND via LED and its 300R resistor? Will it work as sort of pull-down during reset (to boot from main flash)?

Comment: Below the LED's forward voltage, the LED's impedance is undefined and rapidly approaches an open circuit. This is not what is wanted for a pulldown : always use a resistor in parallel.

Comment: @user_1818839 That is exactly the reason I asked the question. But then the next question would be - is there a voltage present on input pin sufficient to shift the diode into conduction?

Comment: @Maple While the comment about the LED being OC at low voltages is correct, the voltage can be guaranteed to not be above Vf at some low current. **IF** this is below Vlow_max then it will work but the ability for the pin to float between ground an Vf may have some second order effects.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon so basically, don't be a smart a** and add a traditional pull-down like normal people do. Seems to be a consensus in majority of comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not guaranteed to work due to LED being sensitive to light and having some parasitic capacitance. To be 100% reliable under all conditions, it requires a separate pull-down resistor.

That's because a LED will also act as a photovoltaic cell, and due to light that hits the LED it will output voltage.

I just measured that a random SMD LED with series resistor will measure 1.24V in bright light. The multimeter input impedance is rated above 10 Mohm, but the voltage will be higher with no load impedance at all and just the MCU.

So even with the multimeter, LED output voltage is already above typical CMOS input voltage requirements for a logic low level.

In practice, the MCU could still understand that as logic low, and the voltage will be lower under normal lighting conditions. I used a flashlight for demonstration purposes.

Many other circuits with LEDs connected to pins that are potentially three-stated or occasionally inputs (such as GPIO expanders) also suggest a resistor over the LED to shunt the photocurrent to avoid indeterminate floating voltages.

Also the LED semiconductor junction has some smallish amount of capacitance, in the order of 10 to 100 picofarads.

If you turn on the LED and reset the MCU, it takes some time for the charge to decay, and until it does, the GPIO pin will read as a high input. An external resistor will also make sure to discharge this charge. In some circuits, the LED capacitance can be used to measure light levels, by measuring how long it takes for the photocurrent to charge the capacitance - effectively making the LED a bidirectional communication device.

Comment: What if we "flip" the LED polarity? Won't that produce a slightly negative voltage on the pin (pull it below 0V) and since the power will be so small, the protection diodes will rectify that?

Comment: @akwky it would, but then it wouldn’t emit light when the GPIO was set high.

Comment: A single package back to back LED may work. But not liable to also be lowest cost.

Comment: I'd say the obvious way around this is to add the 10k pull-down in parallel to the LED, this should keep the photo-voltage low enough.

Comment: Related read: https://hackaday.com/2014/03/06/the-mystery-of-zombie-ram/

Comment: I once saw an EEPROM change values at 120Hz because of a fluorescent light overhead.  Using an LED or other photosensitive component in this way could make debugging and field service... interesting.

Comment: Interesting. By this logic no LED with Vf > 2.5V would work outdoors from 3.3V source. And yet I never heard of this happening. Can' help feeling there is more to it than simple voltage subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

sure; you only have to make sure the voltage is below the low/high threshold given how much current will (inevitably) flow out of the boot input.

Look at table 62 of the datasheet: the leakage of the boot pin should be in the range of at most 100 nA, so 3·10² Ω · 10⁻⁷ V = 0V over the resistor, and 0 V over the LED's junction, making it pretty sure that the voltage at the boot pin is below the low-max voltage of 0.3 · VDD.

Comment: This is encouraging. Another option for me was to use [NUD3160](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/on-semiconductor/NUD3160LT1G/920234) driver with its built-in 100k pull-down on the input. Splitting hairs here, trying to minimize costs and PCB size simultaneously.